# Velocity as a scalar quantity in regards to KE

Tags: kinematics

As the title would imply, I’m questioning why velocity is considered a scalar value when measuring the kinetic energy of a system. From my understanding, it’s a result of it being squared in the formula — but why is that so? What makes this procedure “able” to change that quantity’s status?

Comment: kinetic energy  of a mass does not depend on the direction of the velocity, and v^2=<v,v> is a scalar.

Comment: I now understand. I must thank you all 

Comment: Both of the present answers are solid, so you should accept one to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

While measuring the kinetic energy of a system, with $K =\sum_{\alpha} \frac{1}{2} m_\alpha v_\alpha ^{\space 2}$, here $v_\alpha$ refers to the (instantaneous) **speed** of the particle with index $\alpha$, and not the velocity. The magnitude of the instantaneous velocity is equal to the instantaneous speed, so we are not changing the vector nature of velocity, but simply using it's magnitude.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian mechanics

KE of a body =$\frac 12 m v^2$

in which $m$ is the mass of the body and $v$ is its speed.

Speed is a scalar quantity. It is the magnitude of the body's velocity.

Comment: Understood, thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

For a velocity vector $\vec v$ with speed $v=|\vec v|$ we have $v^2=\vec v \cdot \vec v=|\vec v|^2$. It is pretty standard notation, but it can be surprising the first time you see it.